# Android same drawables for multiple res/screen width options

Tags: android

In my Android app, I would like to provide the exactly same pngs for the sw600dp-mdpi folder as for the hdpi folder. Is there any option other than having the resources duplicated in both folders?

Comment: `SVG`s *insertheartemoji*

Comment: Any reason for having same pngs in both folder ?

Comment: @VivekMishra our mdpi graphics for phones don't look good on mdpi tablets.

Comment: you can keep them in drawable folder directly

Answer (score 1):

You have two solutions:
Either you only provide the files in the default resources fallback, Or you also provide a file that is larger from default one in the HDPI resources. Android will pick the best that suit the device.

make sure about the quality and how it looks in multiple screen sizes.

Comment: Thank you; however, I didn't mention that would also like to provide a sw600dp-hdpi folder with the same resources as in xhdpi, so stuff gets more complicated (default drawable folder solution won't work for both).